# HTML Canvas not working with React, code is not giving any error

Tags: reactjs

Here is the code which I am trying, I am trying to draw brush strokes on mouse move event using react. I am new to react so I saw this particular approach on the internet. Please help me with this. What am I missing?

I have even tried copy-pasting the exact code from a youtube video still it's not working

Thank You

```
import React , { useRef, useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';


import './index.css'

function App(){
  const boardRef = useRef(null);
  const [isDrawing, setIsDrawing] = useState(false)
  const contextRef = useRef(null)

  const startDrawing = (e) => {
    contextRef.current.beginPath()
    contextRef.current.moveTo(e.offsetX, e.offsetY);
    
    setIsDrawing(true)
  }

  const finishDrawing = () => {
    contextRef.current.closePath()
    setIsDrawing(false)
  }
   const draw = (event) => {
     
     if (isDrawing) {
      contextRef.current.lineTo(event.offsetX, event.offsetY);
      contextRef.current.stroke();
      
    }
     
   }
    
  
    useEffect(() => {
    const board = boardRef.current
    board.width = window.innerWidth;
    board.height = window.innerHeight;
    const context = board.getContext('2d')
    
    context.scale(2, 2);
    context.lineCap = "round" ;
    context.lineJoin = "round" ; 
    context.lineWidth = 5;
    context.strokeStyle = "black"

    contextRef.current = context
  }, [])
 
    return (
        <canvas id="whiteboard" ref={boardRef}  onMouseDown={startDrawing} onMouseUp={finishDrawing} onMouseMove={draw}></canvas>
    )
}
ReactDOM.render(<App/>,document.getElementById('root'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`e.offsetX` represent `undefined` value you need to use `e.nativeEvent.offsetX`.

same goes for `e.offsetY`, you need to use `e.nativeEvent.offsetY`.

here is the [code snippet](https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-draw-html-canvas-szydj?file=/src/App.js)